# mac ssh fails in user mode succeeds in root mode for same private key

Tags: ssh, authentication, openssl, mac, osx-yosemite

*System Configuration:*

```
MAC Version : 10.10.5  
    uname -a
    Darwin xxxxx-xxxx 14.5.0 Darwin Kernel Version 14.5.0: Tue Sep  1 21:23:09 PDT 2015; root:xnu-2782.50.1~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

*Issue:*
Not able to connect to a server using the SSH private keys with user mode. However same command with same SSH keys (at same location as that of user) works fine with root authentication.

*Failed Output logs (User level command):*

```
> ssh -v -2A 198.18.144.158
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/userxyz/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to 198.18.144.158 [198.18.144.158] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/userxyz/.ssh/internal/2009-01-01.ppk type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/userxyz/.ssh/internal/2009-01-01.ppk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/userxyz/.ssh/internal/2009-01-01.ppk type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/userxyz/.ssh/internal/2009-01-01.ppk-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version Server-VIII-hpn14v2
debug1: no match: Server-VIII-hpn14v2
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: DSA ee:33:bd:ac:7b:6e:bd:0b:60:6e:49:20:56:cb:00:d3
debug1: Host '198.18.144.158' is known and matches the DSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/userxyz/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_dss_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/userxyz/.ssh/internal/2009-01-01.ppk
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/kimanjun/.ssh/internal/2015-11-16.ppk
debug1: key_parse_private_pem: PEM_read_PrivateKey failed
debug1: read PEM private key done: type <unknown>
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

*User level config changes*

```
pwd
/Users/userxyz/.ssh
> cat config 
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/internal/2009-01-01.ppk
>
```

*Success Output logs (Root level command):*

```
sudo  ssh -v -2A 198.18.144.158 
Password:
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to 198.18.144.158 [198.18.144.158] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
debug1: identity file /Users/userxyz/.ssh/internal/2009-01-01.ppk type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/userxyz/.ssh/internal/2009-01-01.ppk-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version Server-VIII-hpn14v2
debug1: no match: Server-VIII-hpn14v2
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: DSA ee:33:bd:ac:7b:6e:bd:0b:60:6e:49:20:56:cb:00:d3
debug1: Host '198.18.144.158' is known and matches the DSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /var/root/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_dss_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/userxyz/.ssh/internal/2009-01-01.ppk
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to 198.18.144.158 ([198.18.144.158]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: DSA ee:33:bd:ac:7b:6e:bd:0b:60:6e:49:20:56:cb:00:d3
debug1: Host '198.18.144.158' is known and matches the DSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /var/root/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_dss_verify: signature correct
debug1: set_newkeys: rekeying
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: set_newkeys: rekeying
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Requesting authentication agent forwarding.
This is a private system.  No unauthorized use is permitted; if you are
not an authorized user, please log off now.
root@198.18.144.158:~# exit
```

*Root level config changes:*
I have changed the root level ssh_config to point to the private key to user level account instead of default rsa key.

*What I have tried:*
a. Tried different permission of the `.ssh` and `internal` at user level folder but does not impact.
b. Tried `ssh-add` but see the output which looks ok.
c. checked the known_hosts at both user level and root level and looks identical.

Not sure what is causing the issue - since at root level I am able to authenticate the key and at user level not able to do the same.

Any help is welcome.

Comment: have a look on the server side. There is error log which should give you clue, why was your key rejected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't specify a specific username on your ssh commandline: you're logging in with user `root` on the remote system when you use `sudo` and your normal OSX user `userxyz` (or `kimanjun` or whatever) when you don't.

Try  `ssh root@198.18.144.158` when you omit `sudo` or `ssh -l root 198.18.144.158`.

If you don't want to log in as root, please use the correct remote login name instead and set up the correct SSH keys.